# How to copy HTTP headers from Charles to Postman

Tags: http, https, http-headers

I have a problem with recreating the headers, everything seem identical, but it just doesn't work. Need those headers to access Instagram API

I tried to use Charles to intercept a traffic from mobile device and it's working as expected, but I'm struggling to recreate the same headers.

URL is https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/user/7499201770/reel_media/

Headers are

```
:method: GET
:scheme: https
:path: /api/v1/feed/user/7499201770/reel_media/
:authority: i.instagram.com
content-type: application/json
authority: i.instagram.com
accept: */*
path: /api/v1/feed/user/7499201770/reel_media/
accept-language: en-IN;q=1.0
accept-encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5
content-length: 2
user-agent: Instagram 10.29.0 (iPhone7,2; iPhone OS 9_3_3; en_US; en-US; scale=2.00; 750x1334) AppleWebKit/420+
referer: https://www.instagram.com/
x-ig-capabilities: 3w==
cookie: ds_user_id=6742557571; sessionid=IGSCf716eb61bf2a6d41f...
```

I tried to use Postman in order to recreate this request, but every time I get the same error "Login required". How should I paste those headers? I can't understand that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the user-agent: Instagram 10.29.0 (iPhone7,2; iPhone OS 9_3_3; en_US; en-US; scale=2.00; 750x1334) AppleWebKit/420+ that I didn't copy

With user-agent it works, so HTTP headers will look like this in case someone writing an instagram story saver)

```
["Content-Type": "application/json",
 "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
 "User-agent": "Instagram 10.29.0 (iPhone7,2; iPhone OS 9_3_3; en_US; en-US; scale=2.00; 750x1334) AppleWebKit/420+",
 "Cookie": "ds_user_id=67425...; sessionid=IGSCf716eb61b....]
```